# How to fasten execution for table having 100 million record for like query

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

i am working on a project where we have 100 millions record in a table. on that table we perform different queries but like query for title is taking too much time. at the time table is in innoDB. We are using aws rds. AWS RDS is not allowing us to convert innoDB to MyISAM. what could be the solution for fasten execution time for like queries if we use innoDb.

Query is exactly like this

```
select table_id from table where title like '%keyword%' limit 10000000,20
```

main problem comes when use 'like' with higher limit offset. 
let suppose we are getting rows which are found at the last of table than query is taking too much time for skipping first millions record while performing limit with higher offset.

Comment: Create Index. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: can i take a look the query that u write for that title?

Comment: There are several ways, depended on your design. 1. scale-up your RDS instance. 2. Add RDS Read-replica. 3. Add more effective index of table. 4. Re-design your schema

Comment: The commenters so far may be overlooking the (key)word `LIKE` in the question title, which implies scanning queries `LIKE '%this%'`.  @Irfan are you familiar with `FULLTEXT` indexes?

Comment: a very big problem is that query takes more than minutes while executing with higher offset in limit with keyword search

Comment: The Like queries in Innodb with postfix % ie., 'keyword%' will use indexes where as prefix % ie., %keyword wll not. This is the limitation of Like Queries in MySQL.

Comment: Also note, that a `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` is kind of meaningless. You might get different data once in a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) For MySQL you can do not so much you can create an index for example over your `title` field and use the `LIKE` statement like you do it now.

2.) Another solution is the MySQL Fulltext search:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

3.) The last thing is to use an index server like Solr or Sphinx but there is a lot more to do to run that server but that depends on how much you try to index at the end and how fast it should be.

Comment: sir thanks. But i had question that either amazon databases can't handle queries like that or not? before migrating to amazon databases, we were using names.co.uk hosting and that was working fine with 20 million records and  MyISAM engine. but to increase performance, we migrated to aws RDS for better performance.

Comment: AWS is fine. You have to use a bigger instance if you need more performance but it's working. And better you use Fulltext for your case that should work.

Comment: and what about limit with higher offset..
as suppose if we search 'red' word in title column, query found more than 1 million records, when give offset which are found at the end of table than mysql query has to skip more than millions rows, which are taking most of the time. if we perform same with little offset than query performs well.